# библиотека vlc на python (linux)

Tags: python, linux, vlc

Доброго времени суток всем! Нужно написать программу на python которая будет воспроизводить видеофайлы из папки в vlc проигрывателе. Причем они должны быть в плэйлисте, то есть один за другим. Написан вот такой код:

```
import vlc

mrl1 = '....1.3gp'
mrl2 = '....2.3gp'

Instance = vlc.Instance('--input-repeat=-1', '--fullscreen', '--mouse-hide-timeout=0')

MediaList = Instance.media_list_new()
MediaList.add_media(Instance.media_new(mrl2))
MediaList.add_media(Instance.media_new(mrl1))

list_player = Instance.media_list_player_new()
list_player.set_media_list(MediaList)

list_player.next()

        player.play()
```

Проблема в том что после запуска крутиться первое видео и затем плеер закрывается. То есть ощущение что он не добавляет в лист второе видео. С 1 видео все работает (repeat и т.д.), но как сделать чтобы в плэйлист корректно добавлялись все видео? Перерыл интернет, увы не нашел примеров для этой функции:( Заранее спасибо.
P.S. может быть есть функция которая просто проигрывает все видео и определенной папки подряд? Это было бы даже лучше.

Comment: Так дык. Сформируйте плейлист в виде файла. Положите его в каталог временных файлов. И скормите его vlc

Comment: Не подходит. Видео будет меняться через определенное время и так сказать приходить извне. Если б можно было так, то никаких бы проблем не было:)

Comment: Сейчас создали плэйлист. Для проверки запустили просто сам плеер. Играется только 1 видео и все. При перемотке на следующее плеер также закрывается. Вот как так?))

Comment: @player Проверяйте после каждого проигрывания файла наличие новых файлов для воспроизведения, например.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблема была действительно в vlc. Криво поставился или ОС криво поставилась. Переустановил ОС, установил vlc, сделал update и все прекрасно:)